# Writing hex numbers to a file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The below code is reading a file called ‘test.txt’ which has hex numbers. The below code is converting these hex number into decimal numbers. How can I write the decimal number to a file instead of printing it out?

my code

```
file= 'test.txt'

with open(file) as fp:
   line = fp.readline()
   cnt = 1
   while line:
       i = int(line, 16)
       print(str(i))
       line = fp.readline()
       cnt += 1
```

Comment: I wonder who thought that removing code from the question was funny.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the [built in print function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) has a file keyword argument. You can use this to redirect your output to a file of your choice.

```
input_file = 'test.txt'
output_file = 'out.txt'

with open(input_file, 'r') as fp:
    with open(output_file, 'w') as out_fp:
        line = fp.readline()
        cnt = 1
        while line:
            i = int(line, 16)
            print(str(i), file=out_fp)
            line = fp.readline()
            cnt += 1
```

Assuming you have `test.txt` with the following content:

```
ff
10
```

Then `out.txt` will contain:

```
255
16
```

As of python 2.7 or python 3.1 you can even combine those two with statements

```
...
with open(input_file, 'r') as fp, open(output_file, 'w') as out_fp:
    ...
```

Comment: you able to show me with using my code above please?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my answer assuming you want to write your output to a different file.

Answer (score 0):

```
 fp = open("file.txt", "w")
 fp.write("your data")
```

should work.

Comment: you able to show me using your code with mine? not sure if i am placing your code in the right place.